# Rotating a sphere to a specific point. Not the camera

Tags: three.js

i need some help on this one.

I have search and couldn't find solutions for this, because all the solutions were about rotating a camera around a sphere.

In my case, the camera is still. I have a webgl globe with points around using latitude an longitude. I just want to click a point and rotate the globe mesh so that it centers that point.

I have the point Vector3, it's latitude and longitude but i can't figure how to do this.

Is someone around that can help me? Or know any example like this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rotate a sphere to match a lat/lon the camera center, you can do this:

```
var verticalOffset = 0.1;
sphere.rotation.x = latitude * ( Math.PI / 180 ) - verticalOffset;
sphere.rotation.y = ( 270 - longitude ) * ( Math.PI / 180 );
```

So then you can call this with a tween:

```
var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(sphere.rotation)
    .to({ x: latitude * ( Math.PI / 180 ) - verticalOffset, y: ( 270 - longitude ) * ( Math.PI / 180 ) }, 2000)
    .start();
```

I have created a jsfiddle demonstrating this, where a marker is set at Lissabon:

http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/208/

---

**Update**

In case the sphere has been turned around a lot, the Y-rotation value climbs up. Then tweening the rotation as suggested above results in a lot of reverse spinning until the point is displayed at camera center.

To avoid this, it is possible to set the rotations via *quaternions*. The tweening must be slerp'ed using a temporal quaternion.
For demonstration purposes I have set the spheres initial Y rotation to `PI * 12.1`, then applying the quaternion.

http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/217/

```
var phi = latitude * Math.PI / 180;
var theta = ( 270 - longitude) * Math.PI / 180;
var euler = new THREE.Euler(phi, theta, 0, 'XYZ');

// rotation (using slerp)  
var qstart = new THREE.Quaternion().copy(sphere.quaternion); // src quaternion
var qend = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(euler); //dst quaternion
var qtemp = new THREE.Quaternion();

var o = {t: 0};
new TWEEN.Tween(o).to({t: 1}, 2500)
      .onUpdate(function () {
        THREE.Quaternion.slerp(qstart, qend, qtemp, o.t);
        sphere.quaternion.copy( qtemp );
      })
      .start();
```

Comment: You need to change the path to the TWEEN library in your fiddle, use a proper CDN path

Comment: finds London OK - +1

Comment: Thank a million Falk. I had to make some changes to my project but the math is correct and help a lot. Now i just have to figure out another issue that comes with this change and maybe i'll get back here :) Thanks again. Perfect answer.

Comment: Cool, Im happy you two like it! Please mark your question as solved by accepting this answer and help others that come along :-)

Comment: Ok here is the problem now. Besides clicking the points and rotating the sphere to that point, i am also rotating the sphere with the mouse, so if i rotate the sphere 4 times, the distance to rotate should account for that and not have to rotate back 4 times also. Did i explained it right?

Comment: When setting the rotations with quaternions, the multiple rotations do not happen. I have updated my answer with this approach and a jsfiddle, try if it works for you.